# how to use the phrase 'see straight' correctly?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've learned the phrase'see straight'. According to Longman Dictionary, it means: see clearly (this is the link: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/think-see-straight). So it is correct and natural to say: 'The thick fog prevented me from seeing straight anything.'? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct object pronoun *anything* should come before the adverb *straight*.

> I can't see anything straight.

For your example, though, the adverb *clearly* fits better:

> I can't see anything clearly.

The use of *see straight* is figurative, as shown by all the examples at your link.
The non-figurative use of *seeing through fog* is better conveyed by *clearly*.

Comment: In the examples using _see, straight_ means _directly_ rather than _clearly_.